# Clickable nodes in Three.js

Tags: three.js, click, nodes

I have a 3D-model that I'm loading through the JSONloader of three.js.

[image]

I want to make it possible that I can click on one of the links of the chain. The model is made in Blender and each link of the chain is a seperate node/object.

For example it should be possible when clicking on a blue link, an alert is fired with 'blue', same for green, etc...

Is that even possible in three.js or should I use other solutions?

Thanks!!

Comment: This has been asked a millions times, do a search for something like "three.js click"

Comment: Yeah, but never a good answer... The things you find is about clickable objects that are made on the spot. I want to click on different nodes of a json-object

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by "nodes of a json object". Loading a JSON model into three.js will create instances of Object3D, same as all the other model loaders. The format of the loaded file should make no difference.

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely possible with Three.js.

There are two parts to your question:

1. How to pick objects on screen?
2. How to identify which one is picked?

Part one is easily answered in many other places. Threejs.org includes a very nice example demonstrating that. It can be found [here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes).

The relevant portion of the code is as follows:

```
var raycaster, mouse = new THREE.Vector2()
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    // Do something!
}
```

`intersects` is an array so you can get the first intersect (i.e. the one in 'front') with `intersects[ 0 ]` or specifically the Object3D node with `intersects[ 0 ].object`.

What you do with that is up to you. Based on your example, I would, when creating each object, add a custom property to the object such as:

```
object.msg = "This is a test message!"
```

This could then be logged when clicking the object:

```
var raycaster, mouse = new THREE.Vector2()
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    if (intersects[0].object.msg) {
        console.log(intersects[0].object.msg)
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to create an object with messages and UUIDs:

```
var messages = {
    "61f2175b-6908-48dc-9131-55ffa11c8581": "Hello world!"
};
var raycaster, mouse = new THREE.Vector2()
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    var uuid = intersects[0].object.uuid;
    if (messages[uuid]) {
        console.log(messages[uuid])
    }
}
```

Hopefully this gives you some ideas about how to tackle this problem!